# Apache + Socket.io result in error establishing websocket connection on Mac

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, xampp

I have node.js with socket.io module in it and the tutorial chat example runs perfectly on localhost:3000.

I also have Apache server where I put all my php files for the project. Server works fine on localhost:8080.

Part of the project is communicating a message upon pushing send button on a form in a page that is created by compose.php script on Apache server. When pushing send a websocket connection has to be established (if not yet) and a test emit is sent. Just like the tutorial chat example. But that never happens.

When examining the problem on Chrome Console/Network errors are:

Console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=dhRg2iHG7dJqL3JEAAF4' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
```

Network:

First:

```
Request URL: ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Content-Length: 273
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Sat, 29 Sep 2018 11:43:07 GMT
Location: ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.2.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: PHPSESSID=aaa8a06d8e58534d5ebbe62919085074; io=BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: WqB/VJfA2Fx/+0BrcHPnBA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
EIO: 3
transport: websocket
sid: BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
```

Then:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MOb913S&sid=BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 29 Sep 2018 11:43:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=aaa8a06d8e58534d5ebbe62919085074; io=BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/compose.php?crate_id=53
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
EIO: 3
transport: polling
t: MOb913S
sid: BFoFZNDQamsdNurlAAIr
```

My rewrite rule setup in .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?socket.io ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/ 
RewriteRule ^/?socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io/
```

I almost certain the problem is in the way I redirect socket.io calls from localhost:8080 to localhost:3000. I am just that bad at networks to completely not understand that. I have tried different configurations, including proxy and reverse proxy settings in httpd.conf such as:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io/
</IfModule>
```

I've been trying to fix this for 2 weeks now, it's driving me crazy. How can I get the socket.io on localhost:3000 to emit info upon request from a page originated from localhost:8080/compose.php ?

Answer (score 0):

As most things I fail to do in life, solution was quite simple.

When running `socket = io();` in a .js file, that is being served by Apache server, the socket object is set uri which is uri of the Apache server, in my case localhost:8080.

By adding this line

```
socket.io.uri = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

the problem is solved. The connection fails to be established right away, but will be established at reconnect attempt.